# Link to review on post

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review

Would it be useful to have an on-post link to the review queue when the post still has to be reviewed? It could look like this (notice the button in the bottom right):

[image]

Of course, a tiny link would do to (perhaps next to add comment or the share/edit/flag links).

**What problem would this solve?**

Sometimes, I review posts where someone else has edited out the useless text already, or commented with a request for code, or explained why it is off topic. The review task actually has been done by that other person, and I think he would deserve the review count instead of me. With a button, you'd immediately notice when a post needs reviewing, and you can decide for yourself whether you want that or not.

This also helps reviewing posts earlier, which can be useful on sites with a small reviewing community (I'm not sure if there are any), and of course is extra service to the (new) user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of review is to get eyeballs on stuff that might otherwise be overlooked. Questions that might need to be close, low-quality stuff that might need to be deleted, etc.

That doesn't preclude doing useful stuff *outside* of review, but if the system is asking for more reviewers then there's a reasonable chance it actually needs *more* eyeballs on something, attention from folks who *wouldn't* necessarily be looking at the post anyway.

This would kinda ruin that.