# Is it possible to find a specific question in suggested edit review?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

I know When a question is under a suggested edit the edit option temprory disapper from there.

So, is it somehow possible to find the question in https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/ ?

I tried to append the question id to the Review   link

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11325242

But the link doesnt exist.

Answer (score 4):

> **TL;DR** - it's not possible to find the suggested edit if you don't have 2k reputation. However, if you want past suggested edits on a specific post (about a week old and more) then it's possible.

Worth to mention, that there is a [pending feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176131/link-to-review-on-post) asking to add a link to the review itself, that will do what you ask for (probably even for <2k users), but it's still not done.

When you will get to 2k reputation, i.e. gain the [Edit Questions And Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) and [Access Review Queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) privileges, the "edit" link won't be disabled when there is a pending suggested edit, but rather look like this:

> [image]

Then clicking it will open the suggested edit review in a pop-over.

When you will get to 10k reputation, you can see the [full history of suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history) (users with less than 10k will see only their own reviews) so you can find past suggestions on a post by searching those pages. There is even a userscript that can help finding them, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306412/447356).

Last but not least, [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) can give everyone (regardless of reputation) access to the past suggested edits, only downside is the data there is not live, but rather being updated every Monday. I have [forked a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/407485/get-all-suggested-edits-on-a-specific-post) originally written by [rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene), that gets a post ID and returns all past suggestions on that post, including their status (approved or rejected) and  time of approval/rejection. For example [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/407485/get-all-suggested-edits-on-a-specific-post?postid=33207823)  will return an old rejected edit that was suggested on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33207823/447356).

---

*Finding a post ID crash course*

- For a question it's easy, it appears in the URL:

  > [image]
- For answer, first click the "share" link under the desired answer, then the ID is in there:

  > [image]

Note: The query on Data Explorer is for Stack Overflow, don't forget to switch sites if you want to see history of suggested edits on post in a different site:

> [image]

Comment: @rene true, but it also requires at least one review decision to be made already. That said, can't SEDE be used to find past suggested edits on a post? (and other reviews as well?)

Comment: @rene cool, are you up for a query that gets a post ID as input and showing all past suggested edits, with link to each suggested edit page? I can do that too if you like, and of course if you do that, better post it as new answer. ;)

Comment: @rene awesome, worthy of new answer! :-)