# Show close and reopen votes in the timeline's daily votes summary

Tags: feature-request, timeline

The timeline shows vote summaries on days where a question received upvotes, downvotes or favorite "votes":

[image: votes summary line showing up, down and favorite votes]

I would like close and reopen votes to be included in this summary (for users with the privilege to cast close and reopen votes).  Particularly for old questions that have been reopened, I am often curious whether the votes came in close together or organically over several days.

I don't have the delete-vote privilege on any site, but presumably they should be included as well, especially as they do not expire.

Comment: Similar to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275795/should-the-new-timeline-view-show-links-to-review-items, but not really a dupe.