# Why did an edit to a closed question apparently trigger two reopen reviews?

Tags: support, review, timeline

Regarding [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10839/bernie-sanders-says-his-campaign-has-made-the-political-establishment-nervous), also [discussed](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4366/non-edits-push-the-question-into-the-reopen-queue-what-to-do-about-it) on Politics.SE's own meta, there's one thing I (still) don't understand: why did one edit apparently trigger *two* reopen reviews, five days apart?

[image]

The first reopen-review was clearly triggered by the immediately preceding edit. What triggered the 2nd review, five days later?

Comment: There probably was a manual reopen vote on the post itself. If you are not a moderator on the site you can’t see those in the timeline.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: And those don't show up in the new/spiffy history tab? Is that a bug or a "feature"?

Comment: Why should they show up? The reopen failed. No, I don’t think that’s a bug.

Comment: Feature request to add summaries of close and reopen votes to the timeline: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277132/show-close-and-reopen-votes-in-the-timelines-daily-votes-summary

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I see. I was expecting/hoping that the history attempts to show what triggered review(s), but apparently that's not the intention/scope of the present design.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you are a moderator, not *all* sources of triggers are visible in the timeline.

Reopen reviews can also be triggered by someone casting a re-open vote directly on the post. Since that’s a *vote* to reopen these are not shown in the timeline for anyone below moderator level. Someone almost certainly tried to reopen that post directly from the post itself here.

There is an [open feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277132/show-close-and-reopen-votes-in-the-timelines-daily-votes-summary) to add daily summaries of close and reopen vote counts to the timeline.