# Where can I see how many reopen votes a question has received?

Tags: support, vote-to-reopen

I can see how many reopen votes a question has received shortly after the votes were cast:

[image: Image of the "reopen" button beneath a closed post, with 3 in parantheses, denoting that the post has 3 votes to reopen]

However, after some time, they age away, and the reopen button no longer denotes that the reopen votes are, or were, there. Where can I see how many reopen votes a question has received?

Comment: You can't, if the votes weren't cast from the review queue and the closure/reopening wasn't successful the votes won't be visible.

Comment: Closest thing to this question I've found [is an FR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277132) that doesn't distinguish between votes a review item or outside the Close queue.

Answer (score 4):

Close and reopen votes are in the timeline for diamond moderators, but I'm not sure that a mod would give the information out, especially since I can't think of a compelling reason why you would need it.

But the timeline also shows something that might be helpful: Reviews. If you're lucky, the reopen queue result page may show everyone who voted to reopen ([example](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/427384)). You don't even need any privileges to check this, but for regular users the link to the review only shows up in the timeline after it's finished.

Comment: Did you check for duplicates?

Comment: @bad_coder I looked but I didn't find any questions that were both relevant *and* had a good answer.

Comment: With just [305 Qs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vote-to-reopen) I'm surprised no one asked before.