# Flag post that is already in low quality review queue - any effect?

Tags: discussion, support, review, flags, low-quality-posts

Let's say I see an answer that should not have been one and I flag it as Not An Answer (NAA). On this site I have plenty of reputation and am able to use the *Low Quality* (LQ) review queue and cast delete recommendation votes.

Of course raising such a flag on a still virgin post brings it to the LQ review queue, but **what happens if I flag a post on the main site that is already in the respective review queue?**

Is my flag simply useless in that case? I doubt it would be the same as casting a delete (recommendation) vote from the queue. And when I somehow manage to find that specific post in the review queue later, it's locked down for me, because I have already cast a flag. So was that flag without any effect?

Based on how I currently guess the system works, I proposed two alternative solutions to improve the system in my feature request [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277292/280883). They were first part of this question, but I decided to split the question from the feature requests.

Comment: I think you can get to the review task from the new timeline, though I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom What new timeline? I don't get what you want to describe...

Comment: [Here's the timeline for this very question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/277250/timeline), though there are no review tasks in it, of course.  There've been a few questions on this meta about feature requests, one [specifically about review visibility](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275795/should-the-new-timeline-view-show-links-to-review-items) (which seems to be about removing access to unfinished tasks, so maybe go argue against if you feel strongly).

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Can I somehow access a post's timeline through a link, or do I really have to enter the URL manually?

Comment: I have a userscript I found on Stack Apps; otherwise it's manual.

Comment: I would suggest clarifying and separating out your two mutually exclusive suggestions, perhaps as self-answers; the main focus here for some reason seems to be asking what purpose the current setup has for extra flags (not much except *making it harder to remove the post from review without deleting/closing it*), rather than the point that this should be changed.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I split my question, now the feature requests are outsourced [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277292/280883)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each VLQ/NAA flag raised on a post [adds one more <kbd>Looks OK</kbd> review required before the post can be dequeued that way](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/190581/). (If the post was auto-flagged into the queue, the first manual flag overlaps with it and doesn't have any further effect.)

Other than that, and the effect on helpful/declined flags, there is no other effect of flagging a post that's already in the queue. But preventing careless or hasty reviewers from removing a post before more cautious reviewers can finish handling it is sometimes valuable.

Comment: Do you have a source for that? (I guess you are right, but nevertheless...)

Comment: Thanks, that matches the pieces of information I already managed to collect myself... But could you please cite some official sources to proof your answer?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Now I do. (I shouldn't have posted so late at night but oh well.)

Comment: @ByteCommander: Done, although I'd recommend waiting to accept next time.