# Two feature proposals about flags vs. review votes

Tags: feature-request, review, flags, low-quality-posts

<sub>This feature request has first been part of my question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277250/280883).</sub>

Currently I can either flag a post as <kbd>Not An Answer</kbd> or <kbd>Very Low Quality</kbd> from the main site, or I can review it <kbd>Looks Ok</kbd> or <kbd>Recommend deletion</kbd> from the low Quality review queue, if I have enough reputation.

However, I have no chance to determine if a post I see on the main site and find inappropriate is already in a review queue or not.
In case the post is in no queue yet, the action is clear and has to be a flag that puts it in the queue.
But if the post is already in the queue (which I don't know), I should rather visit the post through the review site and cast my review vote there instead of raising another flag.

As I understand it, flags do not count for the reviewing process other than raising the number of OK-votes that would be needed to remove the post from the queue again. So even if a post got ten (LQ, not spam/offensive) flags by users with enough privileges, that would not automatically make it reviewed.

---

**I have two different proposals how this situation could be improved:**

1. If somebody has the right to review LQ posts, his LQ flags (NAA and VLQ) should have the same weight and effect as a delete recommendation vote through the LQ review queue.

   This suggestion has already been made and explained very detailedly by *@[Wrzlprmft](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/255554/wrzlprmft)* here:
   [Make VLQ and NAA flags equivalent to a negative review in the LQ queue (if the flagger can access that queue)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273410/280883)
   I fully agree with his described proposal.
2. Or the user (with enough reputation) should be able to determine if a post they want to flag is already in a review queue they have access to.

   Then they should get a link to directly visit it there and cast a review vote instead of a simple (and possibly useless) flag.
   Alternatively they could also get a pop-up menu similar to the one for closing questions and directly cast their review vote from the main site.

Comment: Oh, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273410/make-vlq-and-naa-flags-equivalent-to-a-negative-review-in-the-lq-queue-if-the-f is a partial dupe. I'd vaguely remembered seeing that before.

Comment: Yes, that linked question is very similar to my first proposal about making flags and review delete recommendation votes equal if the user has enough privileges.