# Suggested edits information inconsistency in the timeline

Tags: feature-request, bug, suggested-edits, timeline

I just noticed that the timeline now contains suggested edits made on the post. Awesome!

However, I noticed the background is red-ish, same as deleted posts, which hints it's displayed only to privileged users, so I checked in Incognito mode, and found inconsistency.

This is what I see, as high rep user: (probably need 2k) (<sub>[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/277369/timeline)</sub>)

> [image]

This is what I see, as anonymous visitor: (and probably what <2k users see as well)

> [image]

As you can see, anonymous visitors still see there was a suggested edit, when it was suggested, and with a direct link to the review itself, however missing the review result.

Since <10k users can't view Review history of suggested edits (i.e. they see only their own reviews [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history)), I don't think they should see this at all.

Can this please be fixed, or if by design, add the review result as well for non-privileged users?

Comment: I would like to clarify a couple of things here: 1) Yes, as a < 2k user, the second is what I see on the timeline. 2) _However,_ I'm perfectly able to click on the review and see the outcome just fine, so _"Since <2k users can't view Review history of suggested edits"_ is incorrect. I'm even able to view the review item as an anonymous user, by clicking the link in the timeline. 3) I happen to like (and use) this feature, and would rather it _not_ be removed for < 2k users, please.

Comment: @Kendra I'm afraid you got it wrong. By "review history" I mean [this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history) (and its equivalent on any other site), not the direct link to a specific review item which is indeed accessible to anyone. I was indeed wrong, it's 10k privilege, fixed now.

Comment: _That_ makes my second point void, for sure. However, it doesn't make sense to me why you would want us to not be able to see this in the timeline just because we can't view it in the review history. If your point there is we shouldn't see it in the timeline if we can't see it in the review history page, then I would say that _no_ reviews should be shown in the timeline for anyone who can't see that queue's review history. (10k for all, iirc.) My point three stands, though I admit that _is_ personal preference. This feature has its uses to frequent low-rep MSO (probably for all Meta) users.

Comment: <10k users can't see review history, but they can see specific review items if they have a link

Comment: Huh? It's definitely by-design for all users to see review results: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/275796/237685. The bug is not displaying the breakdown for non-2kers.